# How to remove the letter from the colum and the quotation marks

Tags: python, pandas

i have data that looks like

```
y=data['value']
```

```
0        b'1'
1       b'-1'
2       b'-1'
3       b'-1'
4       b'-1'
        ...  
3631     b'1'
3632    b'-1'
3633     b'1'
3634     b'1'
3635     b'1'
```

and I want to remove the b and quotation marks around the numbers

Comment: `b` might indicate binary strings.

Comment: try `.decode()`, and if `b` and `-1` is removed then what is left for `b'-1'`?

Comment: Does `astype(int)` work?

Comment: The solution depends on the type of `data['value']`. What is the type?

Comment: the type is object @yoonghm